# loading sound in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs6, urlrequest

i am trying to load a sound and play it when two nape bodies collide i have the collision detection working but cant play the sound the error is coming from the following code:

```
var collisionSound:Sound;


collisionSound = new Sound();
collisionSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
collisionSound.load(new URLRequest("bang.mp3"));


private function onSoundLoaded(e:event):void
{
    collisionSound.play();
}
```

i have sample code in another script very similar to this thaat works
help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try playing it after it is loaded? Also add error handlers to see if there are any errors while loading the file.

```
collisionSound = new Sound();
collisionSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
collisionSound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSoundLoadError);
collisionSound.load(new URLRequest("bang.mp3"));


private function onSoundLoaded(e:Event):void
{
   collisionSound.play();
}

private function onSoundLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
   trace(e.text);
}
```

Comment: yes i did with no joy i alos put a trace in the onSoundLoaded function that is not exacuting

Comment: If `onSoundLoaded` is not executing your file isn't loading properly. Try adding an error listener and see what is going on.                 `sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSoundIOError);`

Comment: and what goes in the handler function and i presume its collisionSound rather than sound

Comment: Edited my answer, you can trace the error message and see what is wrong.

Comment: Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/bang.mp3    is the error the sound file is in the same folder as the class

Comment: You might need to place the mp3 file next to the swf file.

Comment: Barış Uşaklı is right. All urls that do not include a protocol (http://, app://, etc) are relative to the SWF file. So you need to place the mp3 in the same dir as your SWF and point it to that location (i.e. if you put a folder title "sounds" in your SWF directory, the url would be `sounds/sound.mp3`)

Comment: thanks very much guys i was publishing air for android and set the destination to desktop for convenience of installing an my nexus 7. thanks again.